# Velocity - get FormData from POST request

Tags: html, post, request, velocity

I'm beginning with Velocity and I'm really curious if it's possible to retrieve data sent by POST request just with Velocity and print them on the page.

#### Example HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>

    <body>
 
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <input id="inp1" name="inp1n" type="text" value="asdf"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>

    </body>

    $request.inp1
</html>
```

In the similar manner is `$request` used in XWiki, but I'm curious if it's generally possible to use it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, Velocity itself is just a tiny templating language that works with whatever objects you place in the context. No such objects are available from pure Velocity, some other part of the program must populate a context.

If you're using Velocity as part of a program you're writing, then you can populate your own context, see [this introduction](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/developer-guide.html#thefundamentalpattern) which shows how to create a context and use it when rendering a template.

You can use one or more of the [default tools](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/), especially the [VelocityView Tool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/view.html) which will provide access to the request and response.

Most "applications" that use Velocity, such as XWiki, do provide access to the request and response, using their own mechanism. Check their documentation to find out how you can access the request.